# How to avoid corrupting MS Access when using it as backend for Winfom or WPF

Tags: wpf, database, winforms, sqlite, ms-access

I am Developing small application using windows form application and MS access as back-end

I receive report from some customers that they got error message "'Id' is not an index in this table"

And I don't know why this happen and how to avoid it

How about to switch to SQLite but I see a lot of application use MS access if I don't find a good solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have trouble with Access, so you probably also will with other local file databases.

A step up is to use [LocalDB](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/07/12/introducing-localdb-a-better-sql-express.aspx).

Comment: But this  known problem in Microsoft access and why this is happen I did not find any resources for avoid it and what causes that problem ,Beside not all users has the same problem

Comment: That's what make it nearly impossible to debug. Indeed has you have no control over foreign users' workstations, and most likely the cause should be found in the set up of these and not in your application. Thus, your best option is to work around, and LocalDB is a reasonable way at zero costs.